# Are layer files compatible between ArcGIS 10 and 9.3?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-9.3, layer-file

If I save layer files in ArcGIS 10, can they be opened and modified in ArcGIS 9.3?

Answer (score 15):

No.  I receive this error in 9.3.1:
[image]

You have to save them at the correct version. Right-click on a layer, select `Save As Layer File...`
[image]

Then use the `Save as type` drop down list to select different versions of layer file.

[image: Updated Screenshot of the Save Types]

Answer (score 1):

ESRI products is not backward compatible, as a workaround save as the layer file at version 9.3.1 to open and edit the layer flie at 9.3.1.